# bitmap clipping?

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, clipping

so I have this bitmap I want to use as background on a view, but the bitmap might sometimes be bigger than the view.

let's say my bitmap is 500x500 px
and my view is 200x200px

when I set the bitmap as background for the view, the view get's stretched to the size of the bitmap(500x500)...

I tried setting the gravity to clip_horizontal|clip_vertical but that didn't help...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/old_wall"
        android:tileMode="repeat"
        android:gravity="top|left|clip_horizontal|clip_vertical" />
```

how can I get the bitmap to get clipped instead of the view being stretched to the size of the bitmap?

Comment: `gravity` is ignored when `tileMode` is set. See [Bitmap drawable resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap).

Answer (score 2):

You can always clip your original bitmap in code. Then set it to the view. Where x,y are your starting points and `X_WIDTH`, `Y_HEIGHT` is your ending point. And `iv` is your target `ImageView`:

```
Bitmap bmSource;
Bitmap bmTarget;

bmTarget = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmSource, x, y, X_WIDTH, Y_HEIGHT);

iv.setImageBitmap(bmTarget);
```